# Finding a minimum-bottle neck spanning tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, graph-theory, minimum-spanning-tree

Hi so i'm doing some test prep and i need to figure out parts b and c. I know part a is true and i can prove it, but finding the algorithms for part b and c is currently eluding me.

> Solve the following for a minimum bottleneck tree where the edge with the maximum cost is referred to as the bottleneck. 
>   (a) Is every minimum-bottleneck
>   spanning tree of G a minimum-spanning tree of G? Prove your claim.
>
> (b) For a given cost c, give an O(n+m)-time algorithm to
>   find if the bottleneck cost of a minimum-bottleneck spanning tree
>   of G is not more than c.
>
> (c) Find an algorithm to find a minimum-bottleneck
>   spanning tree of G.

thanks in advance to anyone who can help me out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For *(b)*:

Erase every edge in **G** that costs more than **c**, then check if the left graph is still connected.

For *(c)*:

Do a binary search on **c**, using the algorithm that solved (b) as the dividing condition.

Proof of *(b)*:

Let's say the graph we got after deleting edges cost more than **c** from **G** is **G'** .
Then:

1. If **G'** is connected, then there must be a spanning tree **T** in **G'**. Since no edge in **G'** costs more than **c**, we can tell for sure that no edge in **T** costs more than **c**. Therefore **T** is a spanning tree for **G'** and also **G** whose bottle neck is at most **c**
2. If **G'** is not connected, then there's no spanning tree in **G'** at all. Since we know every edge in **G**- **G'** costs more than **c**, and we know that any spanning tree of **G** will contains at least one edge of **G**- **G'**, therefore we know there's no edge spanning tree of **G** whose bottle neck <= **c**

And of course detecting if a graph is connected costs O(n+m)

Proof of *(c)*:

Say, the algorithm we used in *(b)* is **F(G,c)** .

Then we have

If **F(G,c)** = **True** for some **c**, then **F(G,c')** = **True** for all **c'** that have **c'>=c**

If **F(G,c)** = **False** for some **c**, then **F(G,c')** = **False** for all **c'** that have **c'<=c**

So we can binary search on **c** :)

Comment: hi can you elaborate a bit more on how the algorithm for b works?

Answer (score 1):

```
Ans. a)False,every minimum bottleneck spanning tree of graph G is not a minimum spanning tree of G.

b)To check whether the value of minimum bottleneck spanning tree is atmost c,you can apply depth first search by selecting any vertex from the set of vertices in graph G.

***Algorithm:*** 


check_atmostvalue(Graph G,int c)
{

for each vertex v belongs to V[G] do {
visited[v]=false;
}

DFS(v,c); //v is any randomly choosen vertex in Graph G
for each vertex v belongs to V[G] do {
if(visited[v]==false) then
return false;
}
return true;
}



DFS(v,c)
{
visited[v]=true;

for each w adjacent to v do {
if(visited[w]=false and weight(v,w)<=c) then
DFS(w,c);
}
visited[w]=true;
}


This algorithm works in O(V+E) in the worst case as running timr for depth first search DFS is O(V+E).
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by simply finding the MST of the graph. This based on the following claim:
MST is a MBST for a connected graph.
For a MST, choose the maximum edge e in the MST and the edge e divides the MST into two sets S and T. Then from the cut property, edge e must be the minimum weight among those edges that connects S and T.
Then for a MBST, there must be some edge e' that connect S and T. Then w(e') must be no less than w(e). Thus we know that MST must be a MBST.

However, there is another way to determine the minimum bottleneck. We don't need to computer the MBST. In your question, you actually implies the monotocity of the minimum bottleneck. Therefor we can use binary search combined with the connectivity algorithm to find the minimum bottle neck. I haves seen the use of monocity in other cases. I am a bit amazed that the similar technique can be used here!